# How to efficiently use find command ? please lend me a hand?

Tags: linux, find

```
find ~ -name delete_me -type f -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f
```

Q1.What does it meant by `-print0`, why is it required ?

Q2.Why `/bin/rm` ? why not just `rm -f` ?

This command only delete matched file in `~` directory; it won't delete matched file in subdirectory or sub sub directory..

Q3. How to modify it so that it will find and delete all the matched file in  subdirectories as well ?

Q4. How to modify it so that it will not find into a certain directory ?

Thanks

Comment: is this a school question?

Comment: All unix commandos has man-pages that explain the meaning of a command and its options; have a look at https://linux.die.net/man/1/find and then come back with additional questions if needed.

Comment: I just came from man find. I got this example from man find, but can't understand, because it did not explain to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1.What does it meant by -print0, why is it required ?**

A good place to start is by looking in the manual. At the terminal you can type `man find` an get a good description.  Typically you can also just google for "man find" and get the same / similar manual pages on the web.

The manual for find says about `-print0`:

> print the full file name on the standard output, followed by a null character (instead of the newline character that -print uses). This allows file names that contain newlines or other types of white space to be correctly interpreted by programs that process the find output.

So this writes every file name followed by a null character and xargs with `-0` will read, expecting each item to end with `-0`.  This allows file names to contain a new line character.

**Q2.Why /bin/ ? why not just rm -f ?**

It's not obvious why this was done from your question.

It looks like there's really no good reason for this.  One reason for doing this sometimes is to let you run a comment when the [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) environment variable is not set correctly.  This can be common when running commands in in `cron`.

However in this case it isn't helping anything since other commands (`find` and `xargs`) are not fully qualified.  It should be:

```
 /bin/find ~ -name delete_me -type f -print0 | /usr/xargs -0 /bin/rm -f
```

The only other (highly unlikely) reason would be that your system somehow has two different `rm` commands and you need to specify which one.  But that really is very unlikely.

**Q3. How to modify it so that it will find and delete all the matched file in subdirectories as well ?**

It already does this.

**Q4. How to modify it so that it will not find into a certain directory ?**

You can use the `-prune` option to skip that directory (and its children).

```
# Just editing your version...
find "$HOME" -name exclude_this_dir -prune -o -name delete_me -type f -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f

# More succinctly
find "$HOME" -name exclude_this_dir -prune -o -name delete_me -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

Comment: That man find is very hard to understand. After explanation from @Kusalananda, i can kind of make sense with the statement from man find about newline character and null character. I believe /n is new line character .. but don'tknow what is null character still. Is there way to write it out for easier understand ?

Comment: Does that means find cmd by default listing found filename and end it with /n ?  but it is not displayed on screen .. ?

Comment: In Q2 you said there is no good reason... i got that example from man find.. take a look below.

Comment: Safer `find -print0 | xargs -0` approach
       •      Find  files  named core in or below the directory /tmp and delete them, processing filenames in such a way
              that file or directory names containing single or double quotes, spaces or newlines are correctly handled.

                  $ find /tmp -name core -type f -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f .                            
I copied this from man find.. it said suppose to be safer way, safer than -delete method

Comment: Refer to  your Q4 answer:   Can i specifiy multiple location in -prune to skip them  ? How ? Thx

Comment: @andrew_ysk All characters are represented as numbers: a is `65` b is `66` ... newline is number `10`.  There is a special character called the "null" character which is `0`. It has special meaning and **usually** cannot be included inside other text.  This makes it a safe thing to use to divide up different bits of text, because it will only be the divider, never inside the text itself.  In this case, there's an assumption that file names can contain a new line (`10`) character but cannot contain a null character (`0`).

Comment: @andrew_ysk yes, by default find lists each file on its own line.  More accurately find writes the number `10` after every file name and `10` is read as a new line.  I can't say why the author of find's manual wrote it the way they did.  I only know it's not necessary. I've explained the reasons why you **might** do something like that in the answer.  But try it yourself, it works just fine without `/bin`.

Comment: @andrew_ysk the syntax I've shown says "match exclude_this_dir: delete **or** match delete_me: print0". If you want to add more you can add more "or" clauses with `-o`.  So just add more `-name directory_name -prune -o` to the front of the arguments.

Comment: Thank You. Very helpful of you.

Comment: @andrew_ysk  `man ascii` will list the whole character set with char, octal, decimal and hex values, and the common (shell and C and other languages) escape sequences for them. E.g `012   10    0A    LF  '\n' (new line)`.

Answer (score 2):

1. The non-standard `-print0` predicate means "print the pathname of the found file with a terminating nul character at the end instead of a newline character".  This is to be able to handle filenames that contain newline characters (which is permitted on Unix systems; nul characters can however not be part of a Unix filename).  The command reading the output of the `find` command that uses `-print0` needs to be aware that the entries are nul-terminated.  It's the `-0` option to `xargs` that lets it read nul-terminated entries.

   It is not required.  Neither of

   ```
   find "$HOME" -name delete_me -type f -delete
   ```

   nor the more standard

   ```
   find "$HOME" -name delete_me -type f -exec rm {} +
   ```

   uses `-print0`.  Both commands do the same thing as your command, and should be preferred to using `xargs`. The `xargs` utility could possibly be useful when reading arguments from a file or some other command.  When using `find`, it is safer to use its built in `-exec` facility. There *are* a few thing that some implementation of `xargs` can do that `-exec` can't, like starting concurrent batches of utilities. This is however not used in this exercise.

   It is also preferrable to use `"$HOME"` in place of `~` in shell scripts, as `$HOME` behaves like a variable, and `~` does not.

   Also note that the `-f` option to `rm` probably isn't needed.  It is used to avoid having the `rm` utility *fail* (with a diagnostic message and a non-zero exit status) if the given pathnames are missing, or if `rm` is called with no pathnames to remove.  It also overrides any earlier `-i` (interactive mode) options. But there is no `-i` option on the `rm` command line here, and the given pathnames are guaranteed to exist as `find` is being used to find them (barring race conditions where the files are actually deleted during the execution of `find`, by some other process, between being found by `find` and being deleted by the `rm` executed from `find`).
2. There is no reason to use `rm` with its full path, unless the `PATH` variable's value can not be guaranteed to contain a sane set of utility paths.  It is unusual to have a broken `PATH` and writing scripts that use absolute paths for utilities are prone to break when they are moved to other systems.
3. It does already recurse down into all subdirectories of your home directory.
4. Prune the directory that you want to avoid from the search tree.  For example, to avoid all directories called `avoid`:

   ```
   find "$HOME" -name avoid -prune -o -name delete_me -type f -exec rm {} +
   ```

   Note that we can't use `-delete` here as this implies `-depth`, i.e. a depth-first search.  With a depth-first search, we'd be visiting all the subdirectories and files inside `avoid` before noticing that the `avoid` directory should be pruned from the search tree.

   Another example: Don't enter into the *specific* directory `$HOME/dir/save_me`:

   ```
   find "$HOME" -path "$HOME/dir/save_me" -prune -o -name delete_me -type f -exec rm {} +
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the great explaination, I need to try out more because i tried previously , it does not recursive.

Comment: BTW, what is -o does ?  Is it equavalent to "or"  operator ?

Comment: @andrew_ysk Yes, `-o` means "or".  When there's nothing between two tests/predicates, it means "and".  Tests are evaluated left-to-right. The command that you show will most definitely recurse, or you are running some other command that you do not show (possibly just subtly different).

Comment: Thank you for helping.

Comment: By the way, This find command makes me go crazy! Is there reason for me to still use it after i realized how easy fdfind command is ?

Comment: $ fd find1 find2 ./folder Apparancely this fd command does not work as i like. How can i make it to find : find1 and find 2 both ?  or make it to find either find1 or find2 ?

Comment: To exclude find1 or find2, i can use !find1

Comment: @andrew_ysk You question here is about `find`.  If you want to ask about `fdfind`, ask a new question.

Comment: @andrew_ysk `find` will only iterate one object at a time starting from the *starting-point*. `-name` or `-path` will only test the pattern on this particular object and not on the list in its entirety. You may not search for two or more unique *file objects* on the same iteration, e.g., if you have a path `'./1/a/b'`, then, the first object will be `'./1'`, second `'./1/a`, and the last `'./1/a/b'`, this is why `find -name 'a' -name 'b'` will never work, sure, you can combine *tests*, e.g., `find -path './1/*' -name 'c'` will match the third.

Comment: @andrew_ysk  Debian (only ref for fdfind that I can see) may be in some disarray. At https://manpages.debian.org, man fdfind resolves to fd (in the `unstable` group), and then fd resolves to fdsh. Care is advised.